# Keras ImageDataGenerator -- Class as Save_Prefix?

Tags: python, image, classification, keras

How do I save my augmented images with their class label in the filename? Or, is there a way it knows which class the new image belongs to?

**EDIT:**

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip=True)
i = 0
for batch in datagen.flow_from_directory('data/train', target_size=
(100,100),
    shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size, save_to_dir='data/train/'):
    i += 1
    if i > 20: # save 20 images
        break  # otherwise the generator would loop indefinitely
print("Saved flipped images")
```

I have three class subdirectories inside of data/train. After running this, I can't tell which images have been augmented, although I do see that about a third of the total # of images have been saved. Is there something missing in my code to specify that the images be named by class, and that each class be looped through to create new images?

**EDIT #2:**
Folder structure: data/train
3 classes in separate folders: n02088364, n02096585, n02108089
The newly created images are saved to data/train, not to individual class folders.

Comment: What have you tried? Without providing any example of your attempt(s), you're unlikely to get help!

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE: I added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, finally figured it out. I had specified a different folder to save the images it, but it seems that if the save_to_dir folder is the same as the dir specified in flow_from_dir, then it will save the image with the proper class identifier.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to save the images under a folder having same name as label then you can loop over a list of labels and call the augmentation code within the loop.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator  

# Augmentation + save augmented images under augmented folder

IMAGE_SIZE = 224
BATCH_SIZE = 500
LABELS = ['lbl_a','lbl_b','lbl_c']

for label in LABELS:
  datagen_kwargs = dict(rescale=1./255)  
  dataflow_kwargs = dict(target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE), 
                        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, interpolation="bilinear")

  train_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=40,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    width_shift_range=0.1, height_shift_range=0.1,
    shear_range=0.1, zoom_range=0.1,
    **datagen_kwargs)

  train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
      'original_images', subset="training", shuffle=True, save_to_dir='aug_images/'+label, save_prefix='aug', classes=[label], **dataflow_kwargs)
  
  # Following line triggers execution of train_generator
  batch = next(train_generator)
```

So why do this when generator can directly be passed to model? In case, you want to use the `tflite-model-maker` which does not accept a generator and accepts labelled data under folder for each label:

```
from tflite_model_maker import ImageClassifierDataLoader
data = ImageClassifierDataLoader.from_folder('aug_images')
```

**Result**

```
aug_images
| 
|__ lbl_a
|   |
|   |_____aug_img_a.png
|
|__ lbl_b
|   |
|   |_____aug_img_b.png
| 
|__ lbl_c
|   |
|   |_____aug_img_c.png
```

**Note:** You need to ensure the folders already exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
# We draw a batch of images from the generator
batch = next(datagen)

# batch[0] is the list of images
# batch[1] is the list of associated classes

# We display the batch (here the batch is size 16) and their class
fig, m_axs = plt.subplots(1, 16, figsize = (26, 6))
for img, class_index_one_hot, ax1 in zip(batch[0], batch[1], m_axs.T):
    ax1.imshow(img)
    class_index = np.argmax(class_index_one_hot)
    ax1.set_title(str(class_index) + ':' + index_to_classes[class_index])
    ax1.axis('off')
```

Comment: what is `index_to_classes`?

Answer (score 0):

in your code you can access the class of the generated images with the batch object.
Batch will be a tuple of length 2. The first element is an array containing all the images of the batch, the second element is an array containing all the classes of the images of the batch.